# Is there a way to recover my Chrome Bookmarks?

Tags: chrome, browser

Yesterday I re-installed Chrome. I lost all my bookmarks.
My .config/google-chrome contents

```
ll
total 5380
drwx------ 28 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 10:21  ./
drwx------ 37 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 15:56  ../
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50  AutofillStates/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 10:17  BrowserMetrics/
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh 4194304 јул 12 10:18  BrowserMetrics-spare.pma
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 10:16  CertificateRevocation/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50  ClientSidePhishing/
-rw-rw-r--  1 joaoh joaoh      36 јул 12 10:16 'Consent To Send Stats'
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh 1048576 јул 12 10:17  CrashpadMetrics-active.pma
drwx------  6 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 15:56 'Crash Reports'/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50 'Crowd Deny'/
drwx------ 38 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 10:22  Default/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 15:56  Dictionaries/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:49  FileTypePolicies/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50  FirstPartySetsPreloaded/
-rw-rw-r--  1 joaoh joaoh       0 јул 11 15:56 'First Run'
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 09:19  GrShaderCache/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 08:02  hyphen-data/
-rw-rw-r--  1 joaoh joaoh      14 јул 12 10:16 'Last Version'
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh  136609 јул 12 10:21 'Local State'
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 15:56  MEIPreload/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 15:56  NativeMessagingHosts/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:49  OnDeviceHeadSuggestModel/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:49  OptimizationHints/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:49  OriginTrials/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50  PKIMetadata/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:49  pnacl/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 10:21 'Safe Browsing'/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 08:02  SafetyTips/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 15:56  ShaderCache/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 joaoh joaoh      19 јул 12 10:16  SingletonCookie -> 1698687314722655440
lrwxrwxrwx  1 joaoh joaoh      17 јул 12 10:16  SingletonLock -> joaoh-IdeaPad-9343
lrwxrwxrwx  1 joaoh joaoh      46 јул 12 10:16  SingletonSocket -> /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.5OaBRY/SingletonSocket=
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50  SSLErrorAssistant/
drwx------  4 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:49 'Subresource Filter'/
-rw-rw-r--  1 joaoh joaoh      86 јул 12 10:16  Variations
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 12 10:16  WidevineCdm/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh    4096 јул 11 17:50  ZxcvbnData/
```

I have no Bookmarks in Defaults:

```
ll
total 3508
drwx------ 38 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:49  ./
drwx------ 28 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:49  ../
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 11 17:49  Accounts/
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh 344064 јул 11 17:57 'Affiliation Database'
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh      0 јул 11 17:57 'Affiliation Database-journal'
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:16  AutofillStrikeDatabase/
drwx------  3 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:16  blob_storage/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:16  BudgetDatabase/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:16  commerce_subscription_db/
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh 294912 јул 12 10:49  Cookies
-rw-------  1 joaoh joaoh      0 јул 12 10:49  Cookies-journal
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 12 10:16  coupon_db/
drwx------  2 joaoh joaoh   4096 јул 11 15:56  databases/
```

I tried:

```
grep -R Bookmarks .
```

and got:

```
grep -R Bookmarks .
grep: ./Default/optimization_guide_prediction_model_downloads/fd7bcfb1-80df-49fb-8c95-917558cb3302/model-info.pb: binary file matches
grep: ./Default/Favicons: binary file matches
grep: ./Default/shared_proto_db/000003.log: binary file matches
grep: ./Default/Web Data: binary file matches
./Default/Bookmarks:         "name": "Bookmarks bar",
grep: ./Default/History: binary file matches
grep: ./Default/Service Worker/ScriptCache/7ac4c22e06202ba7_1: binary file matches
grep: ./Default/Service Worker/ScriptCache/7ac4c22e06202ba7_0: binary file matches
grep: ./Default/Service Worker/CacheStorage/8f7abdeb3486c1b8780fede76afc20e044eff1b5/2f6379b1-afc7-4f79-8c95-d8e0052d9f0b/905e84abf6e1fc2c_1: binary file matches
```

Is there any chance of recovering my bookmarks?

Comment: What's in `Default`? There must be a `Bookmarks` file there. If it's not what you had, binary grep your partition for `date_last_used`. You'll find your bookmarks this way. If you have SSD/NVMe mounted with `discard`, you've probably lost them forever.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov How to check how SSD/NVMe mounted config?

Answer (score -1):

Bookmarks would not be in chrome's .config file, but rather in `Users/<yourname>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Defaults`. The files would be called `Bookmarks` and `Bookmarks.bak` (the backup file). It seems you don't have the file in your `Defaults` folder though, which is strange.

There might be a chance that it's stored in another directory. You can find this under `Profile Path:` when you search [chrome://version/](https://chrome://version/).

You might also have a Time Machine Backup you can look through. You may also find [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) useful.

Next time, remember to sync your chrome account so that when you login on another device or fresh install, all your bookmarks are saved. Otherwise, I'm not sure what to recommend.
Hope this helps and have a nice day.

Comment: Likely ChatGPT (based on this user's other "contributions")

Comment: What do you mean? Why don't you actually read my posts instead of flagging all of them as ChatGPT, @DavidW?